# Branches and Pull Requests are not visible in SonarQube dashboard?

Tags: git, maven, github, sonarqube

I am using SonarQube's Developer edition (8.4) with GitHub (community edition - not enterprise) to analyze Maven based java projects. I took this [sample project](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples/tree/master/sonarqube-scanner-maven/maven-basic) and followed all the steps mentioned in [this guide](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/github-integration/) to set up.

I have a sample build.yaml file copied from the same tutorial, for a Maven project that looks like below:

```yaml
name: Build
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - develop
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0  # Shallow clones should be disabled for a better relevancy of analysis
      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 11
      - name: Cache SonarQube packages
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: ~/.sonar/cache
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-sonar
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-sonar
      - name: Cache Maven packages
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: ~/.m2
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-m2-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-m2
      - name: Build and analyze
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}  # Needed to get PR information, if any
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
          SONAR_HOST_URL: ${{ secrets.SONAR_HOST_URL }}
        run: mvn -B verify org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:sonar
```

Whenever a new code is pushed an analysis is done. I can see PR decorations and checks running for PRs as well in github's dashboard.

However, I am not seeing any other branches except `master` or any Pull Requests in SonarQube's dashboard under ***Branches & Pull Requests***. Below are the screenshots for reference:

***Branches (only master branch is visible. I have feature and develop branches too)***
[image: Branches tab Screenshot]

***Pull Requests***
[image: PR Tab screenshot]

As per SonarQube's docs, I should be able to see multiple branches and PRs in the dashboard.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I would guess either 1.) It's a different repo! Or 2.) SonarQube isn't refreshing for some reason. Maybe there's a config somewhere for how often it should fetch? You could try clicking on `master` in SonarQube's dashboard to see what commit it's on. Then find that commit in your repo and you might get more insight into the last time SonarQube was refreshed.

Comment: I just noticed you said, "Whenever a new code is pushed an analysis is done." Does this mean whenever you push, SonarQube is triggered and attempts something? If yes, then it must be refreshing regularly to see your pushed updates, meaning my previous comment is not relevant.

Comment: Have you tried this **Adding pull request decoration to a manually created or existing project** from the [guide](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/github-integration/)

Comment: @SouravAtta Yes, I have. In fact, I deleted the GitHub repository and SonarQube project once just to make sure everything is okay. I have added develop branch in the build.yaml file too. Everything else is working as expected only "Branches and Pull Requests" tab in the project is failing to show the details

Comment: The doc you linked mentions in the Prerequisites: 'To add pull request decoration to Checks in GitHub Enterprise, you must be running GitHub Enterprise version 2.15+.' and you have "community edition", so that might be a reason for weird behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

As a general remark, you should always consult the doc *for your specific version*. In this case: [PR Decoration for SonarQube 8.4](https://docs.sonarqube.org/8.4/analysis/pr-decoration/).

*(According to that doc, if you meant Github.com by "community edition", it should be supported, so nevermind my previous comment.)*

The link [in the header of this doc page](https://docs.sonarqube.org/8.4/analysis/pull-request/) mentions the following keys that should be passed to Maven when running Sonar: `sonar.pullrequest.key`, `sonar.pullrequest.branch`, `sonar.pullrequest.base`.

Example (inspired by [here](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/missing-blame-information-for-maven-project-with-github-action/34169), may need some tweaking):

```
 mvn -B verify org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:sonar -Dsonar.pullrequest.branch=${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }} -Dsonar.pullrequest.base=${{ github.event.pull_request.base.ref }} -Dsonar.pullrequest.key=${{github.event.pull_request.number}}
```